# Check validity of select box on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm using the native `checkValidity()` method on the [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement) and there seems to be  some problems in non-Firefox browsers.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RxN6Q/)

### JavaScript

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    alert(this.checkValidity());
});
```

### HTML

```
<select required>
    <option></option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

In Firefox, the expected results show. In Internet Explorer, it is always valid no matter what option is selected. In Chrome, it checks the validity of the value of the element **before** the change.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a bug in Blink and Trident, and if so, is there a workaround apart from doing `this.value === ''`?

Comment: which IE version you using right now? as mention in firefox, it only work with HTML5, so if IE version is lower than IE9, theres no chance for this to work

Comment: Latest stable, Internet Explorer 11

Comment: I tried with IE10 and latest chrome. No problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't imperative that you have an empty option then you can get this to work by adding some text to the empty option.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of constraint validation?

Comment: I guess so, but isn't using an empty option tag bad design? You won't ever need to validate a select because the values are pre determined by you. What ever server script you use to handle your form will also get your values and you would process them there. This function seems more useful for when you have some variable user input that you can't anticipate the existence of.